# Complex SPARQL request for owl

Tags: sparql, owl

I got two owl Classes: `ClassAB` and `ClassYZ`

I got 4 individuals: `A`, `B` instances of `ClassAB`; and `Y`, `Z` instances of `ClassYZ`.

I have two object properties: `Need` and `DontNeed`

So I got:

```
A Need Y

A Need Z

B Need Y

B DontNeed Z
```

Now I want all Individuals who are needed from `A` and `B` but not those ones who are not needed from `A` or `B`. So the result should be only `Y`. In future I want to make this with a lot of more individuals.

I can't figure out how I have to make the SPARQL request.

Kindly Regards

Comment: And you tried what? Show the SPARQL query that you have so far. I can't believe that you're not able to add simple triple patterns with the predicate `Need` and a `FILTER NOT EXISTS` containing a triple pattern with the predicate `DontNeed`. See https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#negation

Comment: Thank you! This filter helped me

Comment: If you have, you could/should provide an answer here. This might helps others having similar problems.